# How can I reach the path link in the details sidebar when the activity constantly refreshes?

Tags: excel, query

Dont really know how to expand on the title, but im querying excel files in a sharepoint folder.

Someone has changed the name of the files which has broken the links, so I am restablishing them. When i go to the sidebar for the direct path link. The activity constantly refreshes and i can never click the button in time. There MUST be a way to stop this.

Thanks

Comment: Try switching view to **View: Comments** instead of **View: All activity** from details pane. It will work for you if there are less (or no) comments than all activities on the file. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No this did not work, I do not have a sidebar that has this option. My details sidebar has "Access" "Properties" and "Activity". At the very bottom there is Type, Modified, Path, and Size. I cannot access Path as activity constantly refills the scroll area

Comment: At the right hand side of Activity heading, there is small drop down with 2 options - View: Comments and View: All activity. Use View: Comments option. Can you add screenshot of your sidebar near activity heading?